# trivial regex assistance

Tags: php, regex

I have a string as follows:

`$str="1-3";`

When I pass it through here:

```
preg_match('#(\\d+)\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)#', $str, $matches);
```

I get:

```
$matches[0] //1-3

$matches[1] //1

$matchers[2] //3
```

Now if you hass something like this:

```
$str="a-3";
```

You get

```
$matches //empty
```

This is correct since it is restricted to only integers.

Now my problem is i want to implement something that functions the same however for characters.

**Here's what I have so far**

```
preg_match('#(\\w+)\\s*-\\s*(\\w+)#', $str, $matches);

$str="a-d"
```

I get:

```
$matches[0] //a-d

$matches[1] //a

$matchers[2] //d
```

Which works great, however if u do this (notice the integer):

```
$str="a-5"
```

I get:

```
$matches[0] //a-5

$matches[1] //a

$matchers[2] //5
```

What i need is to enforce only alphabetic characters on the subsequent regex expression - thus if you pass `a-5` it should be marked as errored.

**Essentially i need the first regex solution applied to the second one with characters only**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Change the capturing group to `([a-zA-z]+)`, Like([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/O4A9zE/3)):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s*-\s*([a-zA-Z]+)
```

`\w`, works by matching, any alphanumeric characters and `_` underscore. If you only want to match alphabets then you need to provide the alphabets range like 
`a-z` small letter and `A-Z` capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use unicode property `\pL` that means any letter in any language:

```
$arr = [
'a-d',
'1-5',
'1-d',
'ç-é',
];
foreach($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/(\pL)\s*-\s*(\pL)/u', $str, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches);
    } else {
        echo "$str : error\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-d
    [1] => a
    [2] => d
)
1-5 : error
1-d : error
Array
(
    [0] => ç-é
    [1] => ç
    [2] => é
)
```